# Batch Map about 3000 Parquet files in Hadoop separately, how do it efficient?

Tags: pandas, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

### About the data

The data used for analysis is saved as parquet file on Hadoop, about 3000+

### About the task

I want batch map those files use a map function, each file is separated, the map function use pandas dataframe to get the result, then I need collect all the map result.

### My poor code...

```
def map_func(df):
...:     pdf = df.toPandas()
...:     return some_other_func(pdf)

#first load data
df1 = spark.read.load("/data/file1")
result1 = df1.map(map_func)

...

dfN = spark.read.load("/data/fileN")
resultN = dfN.map(map_func)

final = (result1, ... , resultN)

# How to batch the above process
```

How can I simply this task efficiently?

Comment: Best advice is don't call `toPandas()`. That negates (by a lot) the speed up you get from parallel processing. Figure out how to do your pandas operation using spark DataFrames. Care to share what `some_other_func()` is doing?

Comment: @pault  thx,   some_other_func()   depend on  a third-part lib(talib), it's method need a numpy.ndarray input, so i call toPandas().

Comment: @pault I'd say don't use Spark if you can use Pandas. You can easily parallelize process anyway.

Comment: @user6910411 agreed if using only pandas is an option. My main point was about calling `toPandas()` being a costly collect operation.